# Flutter - Ignoring Thumbs Down

Tags: flutter, dart

Question for flutter.  I'm thinking of creating an app for my 2 1/2 year old son.  He loves the tablet and he's getting quite good at the gestures (tablet technology is awesome for children.)

One thing I've had trouble breaking him out of the habit of and also something that is difficult to convey to a child is that if you keep your thumb down on the screen, alot of the gesture mechanism's don't work.

Now, would there be a way to ignore thumbs down and still allow gestures?

The problem is that kids (or at least mine) have trouble holding the phone/tablet the way adults have accustomed themselves to: without touching the screen.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did you mean that long press would not be working? In your own app you could add the gesturedetector and make long press works like normal press. Otherwise I might have misunderstood you. Maybe you can explain the problem a bit more detailed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What he often does is hold the tablet with both of his thumbs down on the screen.  So I have to take his thumbs off to show him that to make a swipe, his thumbs have to be up.  I was just wondering if it would be possible to ignore say one thumb down and still allow a swipe.  He is in permanent long press :)

Comment: Hm, that sounds really difficult. :-)

Comment: Yes, plus it's tough because, now that I think about it, it would be reinforcing bad habits to shortcut this - considering pretty much all apps don't allow this behavior!